# How to get last message from every conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have messaging system where i want to get the last message from every conversation so i can show it in message notification panel, I have two tables
convo id are unique & so does username

```
convo_id|from_user | to_user   |  updated
========================================
    1   |  user1   |    user6  |  1463311906
    2   |  user2   |  user7    |  1463311906
    3   |   user8  |   user1   |  1463311906
    4   |   user4  |   user9   |  1463311906
    5   |  user5   |   user10  |  1463311906
```

here is the chat table, it stores all messages * details of message

```
    id |convo_id|from_user | to_user   |  updated    | message
    =========================================================
    1  |    1   |  user1  |   user6    |  1463311906 | hello
    2  |    2   |  user1  |   user6    |  1463311906 | hi
    3  |    3   |  user1  |   user6    |  1463311906 | howdy
    4  |    3   |  user8  |   user1    |  1463311906 | great
    5  |    2   |  user8  |   user1  |  1463311906   | good
```

Now all i want is to get the last message of every conversation, for e.g
my username is "user1" and i have messaged "user6" so in chat table as you can see i have messaged user6 three times so i want to get the last message from those three message

and as you can see in conversation table user8 has message user1 two times which is me, so i want to get that last message also. 
how can i achieve this?

here is what I've tried

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test_convo
WHERE
    to_user = 'user1'
        OR from_user = 'user1'
```

this is the result i got from convo table

```
'1', 'user1', 'user6', '1463311906', '0'
'2', 'user8', 'user1', '1463311906', '0'
```

As I'm using while loop how can i get last message of every conversation from chat table

Comment: Is `updated` a timestamp? And why are its values all same?

Comment: you have to use order by ASC in query

Comment: @Reno it is a dummy data to tell you what i want

Comment: Just to confirm you want "Howdy" in user1 and user6 conversation. Right ?

Comment: @AniketSingh Can we get the last message which has max updated?

Comment: @AshutoshArya yes i want to get the last message of every conversation like in above table it is howdie & good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the max ID per conversation ID which is the last message and then join that derived table with the chat table to get the message and any other info:

```
  select c.maxid as chatID,d.from_user,d.to_user,c.convo_id,d.message 
  from tblchat d 
  inner join  (select max(b.id) as maxID,b.convo_id  
  from tblconv a 
  inner join tblchat b 
  on a.convo_id=b.convo_id 
  group by b.convo_id) c 
  on c.maxID=d.id
```

Comment: your query is getting all last messages of every username whether I've messaged him or not

Answer (score 1):

you can use "IN" function here id is auto increment so by default you will get the max id.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_convo tc 
where tc.id in ( select last(tc1.id) 
    from      test_convo tc1 
    where tc1.to_user = 'user1') or tc.id in 
         (  select last(tc2.id)   
            from test_convo tc2 
            where tc2.from_user =  'user1');
```

else if you are using MYSQL then you can use by limit

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_convo tc 
where tc.id in ( select last(tc1.id) 
    from      test_convo tc1 
    where tc1.to_user = 'user1' order by id desc limit 1) or tc.id in 
         (  select last(tc2.id)   
            from test_convo tc2 
            where tc2.from_user =  'user1' order by id desc limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use May be this can help you:

```
SELECT max(YOURID),TABLENAME.* 
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY yourid
```